# How do I parse a json-object?

Tags: .net, regex, json

Im currently trying to filter some information from a file we have coming to our application from a web server

the format the information is currently in is :

```
{"ns2":"ns2.xxxx.xxx","ns1":"ns1.xxxx.xxx","classname":"com.logicboxes.foundation.sfnb.order.domorder.DomCno","privacyprotectedallowed":"true","isOrderSuspendedUponExpiry":"false","noOfNameServers":"2","isprivacyprotected":"true","classkey":"domcno","isImmediateReseller":"false"}
```

What we would like to do is extract the information piece by piece but we are trying to start with the NS2 and NS1 fields

Before we had the following to format our data but i couldnt seem to change it around to make it filter out the above string

```
Dim m As New Regex("(?<=<div id=""xxxx"">).+(?=</div>)")
```

I was wondering if someone here could give me a path to go down

Thanks

Comment: this is JSon, use a JSon parser, (NewtonSoft.Json is the first that come to my mind)

Comment: Just for your information - that new information blob is a JSON object. There are plenty of parsers available already. No need to use clunky regular expressions. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can do something like this:

Your JSON result as a .net object

```
string json = "{"ns2":"ns2.xxxx.xxx","ns1":"ns1.xxxx.xxx","classname":"com.logicboxes.foundation.sfnb.order.domorder.DomCno","privacyprotectedallowed":"true","isOrderSuspendedUponExpiry":"false","noOfNameServers":"2","isprivacyprotected":"true","classkey":"domcno","isImmediateReseller":"false"}";


public class Blob
{
      public string ns2 {get;set;}
      public string ns1 {get;set;}
      public string classname {get;set;}
      public bool privacyprotectedallowed {get;set;}
      public bool isOrderSuspendedUponExpiry{get;set;}
      public int noOfNameServers{get;set;}
      public bool isprivacyprotected{get;set;}
      public string classkey{get;set;}
      public bool isImmediateReseller{get;set;}
}
```

You can use this library to convert it: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Here's the example:

```
var Blob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Blob>(json);
```

Hope this helps you out!

I would also recommend to take a look at the ContractResolvers, so you can use PascalCasing for your properties. More info can be found [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)

If you don't want to create the Blob object, you can also try this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
string ns1 = (string)obj["ns1"];
string ns2 = (string)obj["ns2"];
```

Comment: In .Net 4.0 we now have DataContractJsonSerializer as part of framework. [Here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx) is post how to use it.

Comment: Did you take a look on the crappy performance of this serializer? http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx :-) i prefer this one.

Comment: True, it looks bad. But still for data like that I think you can suffer this performance issue in exchange for not having to extend your codebase. Beside he's deserializing. There isn't so much difference in deserialization.

Comment: That's true in his case. If he doesn't work that much with JSON data.